# Searching for a way to use `linearKEuclid` and corresponding functions of `spatstat`

Tags: r, spatstat

My goal is to analyse simple point patterns on linear networks with respect to Euclidean instead of shortest-path distance. For the latter distance metric, my analysis relies on `linearK()` and related functions in `{spatstat}`. For the former, I found the promising named function `linearKEuclid()` and further functions [here](https://rdrr.io/github/spatstat/spatstat.linnet/src/R/linearKeuclid.R).

Unfortunately, I could not bring those functions to life on my Win machine. Errors like those occur:

```
Error in xysegMcircle(Y$x, Y$y, D, df$x0, df$y0, df$x1, df$y1) : 
object 'C_circMseg' not found
```

or

```
Error in tapply(stuff$sinalpha, list(ii, jj), harmonicsum) :
object 'harmonicsum' not found
```

There is always something missing.
Probably, a reason for this is that the functions are merely written for internal purposes and under development, see, for instance, [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/spatstat.utils/man/spatstat.utils-internal.html) (cp. "Details").

However, I am hoping for some recommendation making the code around `linearKEuclid()` runnable on my machine. Maybe, someone draws my attention to a downloadable developer version or something comparable.

Comment: Searching for functions on the web is not going to help. You need to install the relevant package(s) to make it work (for example the `spatstat` packages include C code, which must be compiled and loaded). To see the current packages for spatstat, visit `https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your confusion and it is unnecessarily complicated to get this to work at the moment since problems with another package on CRAN prevents spatstat and subpackages to be updated at the moment. Indeed you need to install a development version of `spatstat.linnet` and its dependencies. This is most easily done if you have the package `remotes` installed (and necessary tools to compile packages from source which would be [RTools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) on Windows):

First run (in sequence):

```r
remotes::install_github("spatstat/spatstat.random")
remotes::install_github("spatstat/spatstat.sparse")
remotes::install_github("baddstats/spatstat.explore")
remotes::install_github("baddstats/spatstat.model")
remotes::install_github("spatstat/spatstat.linnet")
```

Now the function should work (you may have to restart R if an old version of spatstat.linnet was already loaded when you updated). Try e.g. the example from the help file:

```r
library(spatstat.linnet)
X <- rpoislpp(5, simplenet)
K <- linearKEuclid(X)
```

Comment: Dear Professor Rubak, thank you very much for the immediate answer. It works fine!